# Is TDengine SQL support do caculate between columns and tag?

Tags: tdengine

I was using TDengine for some times,and I tried to caculate some rate through the tags and columns. The follow is my table structure:

```
create table p(ts timestamp,voltag int)tags(nominal_voltage int);
```

Any calculate SQL is

```
select voltag/nominal_voltage from p;
```

but an I got the error bellow:

> DB error: invalid operation: tag columns can not be used in arithmetic
> expression (0.001368s)

My TDengine Version is: version: 2.4.0.12.

Does some know is there any way to calculate the rate. Or is there any method that TDengine supports for this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, the arithmetic expression is not supported for tag in TDengine. Tag is just a flag that identifies the data table.

Answer (score 0):

I think I can store the tag value as a normal column, and then I can do arithmetic calucate between them

Answer (score 0):

TDengine 2.x does not support calculation between column and tag. It will be improved in a 3.x re-designation.